# React: Default Context Value is blank

Tags: reactjs, use-context

I'm attempting to set a default value through a context (which I'll later update). However I can't seem to obtain the value in the consumer.

I have a `SummaryContext` file which contains two default values `title` and `summary`. This is used in `Body.js` and the `header` value passed on. And finally a `Title` file which needs to render one of the values.

The line `console.log("TITLE.JS: " + {title});` in `Title.js` prints `TITLE.JS: [object Object` to the console.

I'm at a loss as to what I've got wrong.

### SummaryContext.js

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

const header = {
  title: "sdlfkjasdf",
  summary: "kmkmkm"
}

export const SummaryContext = createContext(header);
```

### Body

The line `<WikiHeader \>` contains a reference to the file `Title.js` which is the file I'm attempting to pass these values to.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import WikiHeader from './wikiheader/WikiHeader'

import {SummaryContext} from "../contexts/SummaryContext"

function Body() {

    const [header, setHeader] = useState(SummaryContext);

  return (

    <>   
      <SummaryContext.Provider value={{header}}>
        <GoogleAd />
        <WikiHeader />    
      </SummaryContext.Provider>

    </>
  );
}

export default Body;
```

### Title.js

```
import React, {useContext} from "react"
import {SummaryContext} from "../../../contexts/SummaryContext"
import '../../../App.css'

export function Title() {
  const {title, summary} = useContext(SummaryContext);
  console.log("TITLE.JS: " + {title});

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="detailTitle"><span><h3>The title: {title}</h3></span></div>
    </div>

  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [header, setHeader] = useState(SummaryContext);
```

This line isn't doing what you want. `SummaryContext` is an object with a `Consumer` property and a `Provider` property, each of which is a react component. You want something like this:

```
const [header, setHeader] = useState({
  title: "sdlfkjasdf",
  summary: "kmkmkm"
})
```

If you want that initial state to come from the context file you can, but you'll need to export it, as in:

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

export const defaultHeader = {
  title: "sdlfkjasdf",
  summary: "kmkmkm"
}

export const SummaryContext = createContext(defaultHeader);

// used like:

import { defaultHeader } from "../contexts/SummaryContext"

// ...

const [header, setHeader] = useState(defaultHeader);
```

---

P.S: this line will cause you some trouble:

```
<SummaryContext.Provider value={{header}}>
```

Every time Body rerenders, a brand new object is going to be created for the value, which means that every consumer will need to rerender, even if header hasn't changed. If header is the only thing you're providing, i'd recommend doing:

```
<SummaryContext.Provider value={header}>
```

Or if you need to wrap it in an object, you should memoize that object:

```
const value = useMemo(() => {
 return { header };
}, [header]);

// ...
<SummaryContext.Provider value={value}>
```